# "Not listening" or "over ruled"; which is correct?

Tags: phrases

> I gave certain instruction to my subordinate, but he overruled my instruction and acted on his own.

Is it correct to say my subordinate overruled my instruction?

Comment: No. He 'disregarded,' 'disobeyed,' or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Someone who *overrules* your statements or arguments is in a position of authority. As this definition of *Overrule* from the [freedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overruled) states:

> overrule  tr.v.
>
> 1. a. **To disallow the action or arguments of, especially by virtue of higher authority:**
>
>    *The defense attorney's objection was overruled by the judge.*

Obviously, your subordinate is not in a position of superiority, so *overruled* doesn't work here.

You can use the alternatives suggested by Kris in the comment. "***Ignored***" is also an option.